# How to count how many times a group of words appear in a column, in any orders?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has a column showing pairs of students, such as 'Anna-Bob', 'Anna-Charlie', 'Bob-Dan', 'Bob-Anna','Charlie-Anna'...

I want to count how many times each of the pairs of students appears in that column, in any order. For example, for pair 'Anna-Bob', I will count those that have either 'Anna-Bob' or 'Bob-Anna'.

```
Table

Id Pair
1  Anna-Bob
2  Anna-Charlie
3  Bob-Dan
4  Bob-Anna
5  Charlie-Anna

The expected result should be

Pair        Count
Anna-Bob      2
Anna-Charlie  2
Bob-Dan       1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should seriously consider normalizing your data model and storing each of the two names in separate columns.  That being said, you may workaround this problem by using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        LEAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Pair, '-', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(Pair, '-', -1)),
        '-',
        GREATEST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Pair, '-', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(Pair, '-', -1))) AS Pair,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    LEAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Pair, '-', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(Pair, '-', -1)),
    GREATEST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Pair, '-', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(Pair, '-', -1))
ORDER BY
    cnt DESC;
```

If your table looked like this:

```
Id | Name1   | Name2
1  | Anna    | Bob
2  | Anna    | Charlie
3  | Bob     | Dan
4  | Bob     | Anna
5  | Charlie | Anna
```

Then the query could be simplified a bit:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(LEAST(Name1, Name2), '-', GREATEST(Name1, Name2)) AS Pair,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    LEAST(Name1, Name2),
    GREATEST(Name1, Name2);
```

Comment: Hi Tim. Thank you very much for your answer. I really appreciate your help. Could you please let me know how you answer would be if in case each of the two names is stored in separate columns? I tried to figure out how but still could not be able to. Thank you!